# How can I make textView invisible after one click

Tags: android, textview, invisible

I would like to know how to make multiple `texView` invisible when clicked on it won't be shown at all using only one onclick listener.

Comment: Here's a hint: The `View` passed into `onClick(View v)` is the `View` being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

you can make multiple TextView

```
<TextView
 android:onClick="onInvisible"    
 xx...
 />`
```

in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
    final List<TextView> textViewsToHide = Arrays.asList(
            findViewById(R.id.tvFirst),
            findViewById(R.id.tvSecond),
            findViewById(R.id.tvThird),
            .....
    );

    final View.OnClickListener textViewOnClickListener = view -> {
        for (TextView textView : textViewsToHide) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };

    for (TextView textView : textViewsToHide) {
        textView.setOnClickListener(textViewOnClickListener);
    }
```