# Refresh List View (Custom adapter)

Tags: android, listview

How to update list view data in real time? it's only refreshing on re create (if I finish the activity and re launch it). But otherwise it's not refreshing automatically.

`adapter.notifydatasetchange();` is not working at all. I tried that with handler, button, list item click, options menu item click, context menu item click, but I'm not getting any response. I don't think this approach will work.

My activity

```
String [] titles = {"List option 1","List option 2","List option 3"};
String [] descriptions = {updateDescription1(),updateDescription2(),updateDescription3()};
ListView lv;

public String updateDescription() {
    //live clock!!!!!!!!!!
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    return sdf2.format(time);
    }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(getApplicationContext(), titles, descriptions);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            }
     });
}
```

My adapter class

```
class UserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    String[] titleArray;
    String[] descriptionArray;

public UserAdapter(Context context, String[] titles1, String [] description1) {
    super(context, R.layout.no_icon_list_row, R.id.noIconListDescriptions, titles1);
    this.titleArray = titles1;
    this.descriptionArray = description1;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.no_icon_list_row,parent,false);
    TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.noIconListTitles);
    TextView myDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.noIconListDescriptions);
    myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
    myDescription.setText(descriptionArray[position]);
    return row;
   }
}
```

Now, I can't update the descriptions text; how can I update them in real time?

Comment: use `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: in this method `public String updateDescription() {
//my update text data method
return text;
}
 ` what text returning?

Comment: let's say time, `long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
      
        return sdf2.format(time);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.no_icon_list_row,parent,false);

return row;
   } 
}
```

not right.you can modify below:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if(convertView == null){
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.no_icon_list_row,parent,false);
}

TextView myTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById (R.id.noIconListTitles);


return convertView, 
   }
```

last. if you want refresh data just invoke `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`.Hope help you.

Comment: first you should modify you `getView()` method It's wrong for you to write that. second refresh data,you must modify datasource is `descriptions[]` .so you can invoke`updateDescription`  method after invoke `nodify...`

Comment: how to do that? i don't understand! please show me some code!

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {Handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }

    Handler mHandler = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            // invoke you update message
            updateDescription();
            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0,1000);
        }
    };

Comment: Don't you want to make an automatic refresh？have any problem to use looper?

Comment: no, loper is good, I don't have any problem with that, you're not getting my point at all `adapter.notifydatasetchange()` this, not working at all I tried that with handler, button, list item click, options menu item click, context menu item click, but no response.... that method is dead!!!!!! I think you'll get my point!

Comment: `String [] descriptions = {updateDescription1(),updateDescription2(),updateDescription3()};` are you sure this array has changed?

Comment: No, I'm not. how to refresh that?? a string maybe does auto-refresh. I'm not sure though :p

Comment: I want to give you a simple example. for example:`String [] descriptions = {"one","three","two"};` then `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                descriptions[1] = "two";
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            }
        }` First try the test I wrote. See if it's refreshed. flow my write try it Ok?

Comment: i added looper and it's done `descriptions[1] = updateDescription1; ` xd, thanks a lot bro, you're a good developer :)

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434047/how-can-i-make-textview-invisible-after-one-click/ 

   `TextView tv;
    Button b;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
       b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
       b.setOnClickListener{
           tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

you can add data in following arrays and call notifyDataSetChanged method on listview

```
String [] titles = {"List option 1","List option 2","List option 3" , "List option 4" , "List option 5"};
String [] descriptions = {updateDescription1(),updateDescription2(),updateDescription3() , updateDescription4() , updateDescription5()};

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged is a method on adapter and not on listView

Comment: Can you show where you are calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: onCreate i'm calling `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()`

Comment: you have to call it immediately after changing data.

Comment: how to do that, explain in answer!

Comment: That is what i have mentioned in my answer..  suppose on some button click you want to update listview then just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after making changes in your datalist. I hope you understand.

Comment: I tried that with handler, button, list item click, options menu item click, context menu item click, but not working at all :(

Answer (score 0):

```
public String updateDescription() {
 //my update text data method
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 return text;
 }
```

This will notify that your data has been changed and will draw all the items.

I recommend using recyclerview because there you can specify which item has been changed and only that item will be redrawn (reBinded). using `notifyItemChanged(position)`

Comment: whenever you are changing the content of your array just call notifyDataSetChanged and your changes will be reflected.

Comment: I don't know where you are making the changes.

Comment: the `public String updateDescription()` is live! it changes its text!

Comment: so after you are calling `updateDescription() `just do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: it's automatic !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! `long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); return sdf2.format(time);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your adapter that you made a change. After you perform your logic to update call this method on your adapter

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```